# PL/SQL Retornar valor específico de uma string que varia

Tags: sql, string, pl-sql

Preciso separar uma informação específica de uma string dentro de um campo, no caso apenas o valor `"refDate:dd:mon:yy"`, porém a string varia em cada registro.

Como poderia trazer o resultado desejado?

Exemplo da string:

```
(userId:353910|storeID:702|saleAreaId:|shiftId:5|refDate:30-DEC-20|classificationId:11)
```

```
SELECT* 
FROM xxxxxxxxxxxxx
where start_date between '04/01/21 00:00:00' and '20/01/21 00:00:00'
and PARAMS like '%DEC-20%'
and SUBPROC = 'save_ITEMS'
```

---EDITADO:

Cheguei ao seguinte resultado:

```
SELECT
substr(params, instr(PARAMS, 'refDate')) as dt_ref 
FROM flex.flx_api_log_proc
where start_date between '04/01/21 00:00:00' and '20/01/21 00:00:00'
and PARAMS like '%DEC-20%'
and SUBPROC = 'save_ITEMS'
;
```

Porém ainda preciso retirar algumas informações que ficam além da data: `refDate:30-DEC-20|classificationId:11)`

Comment: Se consegui entender sua dúvida você tem que definir como extrair o trecho da string que te interessa no campo (você diz que varia de registro para registro) e transforma-lo num campo do tipo datetime para utilizar na cláusula WHERE.

Comment: Na verdade eu apenas necessito retirar a informação correspondente à data do campo em forma de string, como mostrei na edição da pergunta, agora só preciso formatar a query pra trazer apenas o necessário. Ex: trazer apenas o "refDate:30-DEC-20" em cada linha.

Comment: "ORA-00939: too many arguments for function"

Comment: (params, instr(PARAMS, 'refDate'),17) - ```refDate:30-DEC-20``` . Resolvido pessoal, muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionou o @Motta Segue resolução:

```
SELECT
substr(params, instr(PARAMS, 'refDate'),17) as dt_ref  
FROM xxxxxxxxxxxxx
where start_date between '04/01/21 00:00:00' and '20/01/21 00:00:00'
and PARAMS like '%DEC-20%'
and SUBPROC = 'save_ITEMS'
```

Essa foi minha primeira pergunta, muito obrigado à todos que responderam!